# Pygame sprite jump with pressed key

Tags: python, pygame, keypress

I'm currently making a 2D platformer, I want the player sprite to jump when it touches the ground and the jump key is being pressed.

I had this at the begging, seeing it wasn't doing what I wanted, I wrote a new code using boolean values.

Original code:

```
if not (event == None):
        if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
            if (event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_SPACE):
                if (self.vspeed == 0):
                    self.vspeed = -(self.speed)*2
```

New code:

```
if not (event == None):
        if(event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
            if (event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_SPACE):
                jump_pressed = True

        elif (event.type == pygame.KEYUP):
            if (event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_SPACE):
                jump_pressed = False

        elif (jump_pressed == True and self.vspeed == 0):
            self.vspeed = -(self.speed)*2
            print("jump is pressed")
```

Sadly, the new code doesn't work and I don't understand why. I did alot of research and tests over the past week without any success. The player jumps when I press the key but it doesn't jump again when it touches the ground.

I need to release the key and press it again to make the player jump. "jump is pressed" only gets printed when I press down.

Looking forward to your help :)

Comment: Don't use `event == None` for comparisons with `None`, use `event is None` (or, in this case `event is not None`) instead.

Comment: Additionally, Python style eschews parentheses in the `if` condition.

Comment: why do you check `if not (event == None):` - don't you have `for event in pygame.event.get()`  which do it automatically ?

Comment: better analyze code of `Platformer examples` on [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=example_code&lang=pl#section_38) (at the end of this page)

Comment: Problem can be because you have last `elif` inside `for event` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code correctly sets the `jump_pressed` variable here:

```
if not (event == None):
    if(event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
        if (event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_SPACE):
            jump_pressed = True
    elif (event.type == pygame.KEYUP):
        if (event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_SPACE):
            jump_pressed = False
```

However, this case

```
    elif (jump_pressed == True and self.vspeed == 0):
        self.vspeed = -(self.speed)*2
        print("jump is pressed")
```

is (almost) never true: the only way it can enter in that condition is that

1. `event` is not None.
2. `event.type` is neither `KEYDOWN` nor `KEYUP
3. `jump_pressed` is True and `self.vspeed` is 0.

You have to change the structure into

```
if event is not None:
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key in [pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_SPACE]:
            jump_pressed = True
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key in [pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_SPACE]:
            jump_pressed = False

if jump_pressed and self.vspeed == 0:
    self.vspeed = -(self.speed)*2
    print("jump is pressed")
```

So that the `jump_pressed` check is performed even when no events are triggered.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I found another problem though, where do I reference the `jump_pressed` variable ? Because if I set `jump_pressed = False` as default, it gets set to `False` in every tick. And if I don't set it, I get an error `local variable 'jump_pressed' referenced before assignment`.

Comment: Add a class field `self.jump_pressed` that you set to `False` on `__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

problem can be because you have last `elif` inside `for event` loop.

You need something like this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_SPACE):
            jump_pressed = True

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_SPACE):
            jump_pressed = False

# after `for` loop
if jump_pressed and self.vspeed == 0:
    self.vspeed = -(self.speed)*2
    print("jump is pressed")
```